# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: axis, invoke, saxparseexception

Here is Axis client code that i am using to hit the webservice
I am getting   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. This is when i send a Soap Message
I get a Socket time out if i send XML with UTF-8 encoded

Both exceptions happen on invoke

Is there a way i can ignore BOM marker on call.invoke which seems to be issue.

Quick help would be appreciated.. thanks

public class WSTestClient { public static void main(String [] args) {
     try{

```
    String acordXMLUrl = "C:\\request.xml";

        File xmlFile = new File(acordXMLUrl);

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
        int c;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
        sb.append((char) c);
        String acordXML = sb.toString();

        Message msg = new Message(acordXMLUrl);

        SOAPEnvelope se;       

        String endpoint ="https://somewebservice/getme";

    Service  service = new Service();

        Call     call    = (Call) service.createCall();
        call.setTimeout(5000);

        call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpoint) );

        call.setOperationName(new QName("http://soapactionurl","getme"));

        System.out.println("Calling into webservice" );

        String ret="";

        try{
       //ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {acordXML} );

        se =  call.invoke( msg);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {

        System.err.println(e.toString());

        }

        System.out.println("Return is:"+ ret);

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

        System.err.println(e.toString());

        }}}
```

Comment: Any update on this? I seem to get something similar when there's a timeout.